# How to access object children values from object children siblings?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm declaring an object with private fields, where some private objects fields depend on value of sibling object values. How would I access them?

Example:

I want to access: `private.fields.url`

From: `private.options.static`

I need to reduce duplication here:

```js
var Hi = (function (parent, $) {
 var public = parent.Page = parent.Page || {};

 var private = {
  fields: {
   url: '#page_url'
  },
  options: {
   static: [
    '#page_url'
   ]
  }
 };

 var form = function () {
  var form = $('form[name=page]');
  var type = form.find('#page_type');

  // hide all fields
  initialHideFields(type);
 };

 var initialHideFields = function (type) {
  var selected = type.find('option:selected');

  if (selected.length) {
   console.log(selected.text());
  }
  else {
   $.each(private.fields, function (key, value) {
    $(value).parent().hide();
   });
  }
 };

 public.init = function () {
  form();
 };

 return parent;
}(Hi || {}, window.jQuery));

$(function () {
 Hi.Page.init();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer / access to an object property inside the same object. Instead you can do something like this :

```js
var private = {
            fields: {
                url: '#page_url'
            },
            options: {
                static: []
            }
        };
private.options.static.push(private.fields.url);
console.log(private.options.static);
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more dynamic, ex callable inside options.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use this so can't accept it. sorry.

Comment: @HelpNeeder what do you mean by `callable inside options` ? can you please elaborate?